# Npm scripts doesn't work the way I want

Tags: node.js, npm

see below:

```
scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/babel  sercer/src --out-dir server/dist ",
    "build:watch": "node_modules/.bin/babel server/src --out-dir server/dist --watch",
    "start:server": "node ./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js ./server/dist/app.js",
    "dev" : "(npm run build:watch) && (npm run start:server)"
  }
```

you know, both of them can work well when I run `npm run xxx` , but when i conbian them like `npm run dev` does,the last one will not taking effect.what wrong with my script?

Comment: have you tried it without the parentheses?

Comment: @Hinrich I have tried

Answer (score -1):

You could try

`"dev" : "npm run build:watch && npm run start:server"`

you can use the `post-` and `pre-` scripts that will be called before and after that script.
 eg :

`"build": "npm run build:css && npm run build:js",
  "prebuild:js": "npm run lint"`

In the above example build will execute both build:css and build:js - but not before running the lint task.